# E-mailing from MSAccess with VBA

Tags: email, microsoft-access, vbscript, vb.net

I am currently using CDO to send e-mails from Access with VBA using SMTP and it works fine.

My problem is when I use SMTP I do not see the sent e-mails in the sent items in the mailbox that I am using. I need this so I can proof to the recipient that the e-mail was indeed sent. Does anyone one have an idea how I can fix this? Any solution in `VB.NET`, `C#`, `VBScript` or `VBA` (as above) will be welcome. Below is my script in `VBA`.

```
Const cdoSendUsingPickup = 1
Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2 'Must use this to use Delivery Notification
Const cdoAnonymous = 0
Const cdoBasic = 1 ' clear text
Const cdoNTLM = 2 'NTLM
'Delivery Status Notifications
Const cdoDSNDefault = 0 'None
Const cdoDSNNever = 1 'None
Const cdoDSNFailure = 2 'Failure
Const cdoDSNSuccess = 4 'Success
Const cdoDSNDelay = 8 'Delay
Const cdoDSNSuccessFailOrDelay = 14 'Success, failure or delay

Set objmsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set objConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

Set objFlds = objConf.Fields
With objFlds

  ''http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/ the .Items must pe prefixed with this

  .Item("sendusing'") = cdoSendUsingPort
  .Item("smtpserver'") = "1.1.1.1"
  .Item("smtpauthenticate") = cdoBasic
  .Item("sendusername") = Username
  .Item("sendpassword") = Password
  .Item("smtpserverport") = 25
.Update
End With

strbody = "Message here"

With objmsg
  Set .Configuration = objConf
  .To = "email@domain.com"
  .From = "me@domain.com"
  .Subject = "EmailSubject"
  .HTMLBody = strBody
  .AddAttachment myfile
  .Fields("urn:schemas:mailheader:disposition-notification-to") = "me@domain.com"
  .DSNOptions = cdoDSNSuccessFailOrDelay
  .Fields.Update
  .Send
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Debug.Print Err.Description
  End If
```

Comment: Look in the smtp server logs

Comment: Yes David, I know about that but I do not have easy access to it because the whole company's emails are in there and they won't give me access to that. Therefore I want it in my sent items.